# Return PDF to WebPage from ASHX

Tags: c#

I have a web page with a "download" link on it.

Using jQuery I do an Ajax Get to a ASHX file.

In the ASHX I get the Stream of the file.  I then convert the stream to a byte array and return the byte array back to the calling html page;

jQuery

```
$(".DownloadConvertedPDF").click(function () {
  var bookId = $(this).attr("bookId");

  $.get('/UserControls/download.ashx?format=pdf&bookId=' + bookId, {}, function (data) { });

});
```

C#

```
context.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Stream fileStream = publishBookManager.GetFile(documentId);
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  int read;
  while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

I don't get an error but also the PDF doesn't display on screen.

Ideally I'd like the pdf returned and the jQuery to launch the pdf in a seperate tab within the browser.

How can I make this happen or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (do not use `.get`):

```
window.open('/UserControls/download.ashx?format=pdf&bookId=' + bookId, "pdfViewer");
```

To prevent the "File does not begin with '%PDF" error, use `Response.BinaryWrite`:

```
context.Response.Clear(); 
context.Response.ClearContent(); 
context.Response.ClearHeaders(); 
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Stream fileStream = publishBookManager.GetFile(documentId);
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  int read;
  while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}

context.Response.BinaryWrite(data); 
context.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: @griegs: use the `window.open` method. I don't think `.get` will work.

Comment: Ah that's much better but am getting an error "File does not begin with '%PDF-'

Comment: Adde few more lines to my answer. Also make sure there is no other html/string being returned (ashx should have no markup either)

Comment: Sorry @mrchief the issue is still the same.  i know the pdf is there and correct and the ashx has no html other than the <%@ WebHandler entry

Comment: No need to be sorry. As I said, that is _dreaded_ error. If you google about it, you'll see all sorts of resolutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Through use of context.Response.TransmitFile, a more concise way to serve a PDF from an ashx web handler is:

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\path-to\your-file.pdf");
context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also using window.open for getting the pdf. but it is always displayed while try to use same URL through address bar directly without logged in. how to solve this one.