# file does not begin with %pdf-

Tags: c#

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101361/return-pdf-to-webpage-from-ashx) and have now got it mostly working.

However I am still getting the titled error and cannot seem to find any reference to anyone that has solved it.

This is driving me insane!

My ASHX C# code looks like this;

```
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.Charset = "";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=file.pdf"); 
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Stream fileStream = publishBookManager.GetFile();
byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  int read;
  while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}

context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
```

And my jQuery / javascript looks like;

```
window.open('/UserControls/download.ashx?format=pdf&bookId=' + bookId, "pdfViewer");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several problems with this code - you write out the content of `buffer` when you *probably* meant to write out the contents of your memory stream, which you dispose of without using - but why not just do

```
fileStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the Acrobat Reader upgraded to the latest version?  Is the file openable in Acrobat Reader separate from coming from the HTTP request?

Also, is the file larger than 32K?  Because it looks like you are only able to hold 32K in your buffer that you are writing out the the caller.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, rather a hack. It might help someone...

I got the same error message when my users were trying to download a PDF which was auto-generated from the site using a direct link e.g. http://example.com/MyFile.pdf.

To resolve it, I changed the hyperlink from http://example.com/MyFile.pdf to http://example.com/MyFile.pdf?

(Notice the question mark at the end of the link)

It solved the problem.

I am not sure how it works really, probably a caching issue!?