# Convert Excel Byte to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, pdf

Firstly, I am converting Excel docs to Byte and storing them in SQL SERVER 2008

```
string[] TotalCount = Directory.GetFiles(FileDropLocation);

foreach (string item in TotalCount)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

    //insert the file into database
    string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
    InsertUpdateData(cmd);
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";

}
```

Secondly, I want to retrieve it as a PDF and not excel and show it on my aspx page.
Can this be done?
Please require assistance on this part.

Thanks in Advance,
HRG

Comment: As far as converting an Excel document into a PDF goes you will most likely need a commercial library such as http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm but if you are wanting to create your own solution I would check out this article to get you started http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17574/Programmatically-Convert-Documents-to-PDFs-the-Eas

Answer (score 0):

If you are allright with installing Microsoft Excel onto your web server you could convert using [Excel's save as PDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb407651%28v=office.12%29.aspx) functionality. This allows you to configure and output the PDF based on Excel quite easily. It won't pop up an Excel window on your server ;)

Comment: But I would need to save the file on the disk, which I don't want since I am only interested in displaying it as a PDF on my browser

Comment: Save to a stream? The stream can be a response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something along the following lines:

1. Get the data from SQL.
2. Convert to PDF using some sort of component e.g. http://www.doc2pdf.net/Excel2PDF/
3. Send the PDF data down to browser in the response, e.g. [Return PDF to WebPage from ASHX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101361/return-pdf-to-webpage-from-ashx)

Comment: I cant use external convertors.

Comment: You're probably going to need some sort of component to do the conversion from Excel to PDF, be it a 3rd party library, Ghostscript as mentioned by David or Excel as mentioned by Bas.

Comment: *I cant use external convertors.* - then you'll have to spend some weeks or months creating your own. Do you really want that?