# Bytes[] to temporal PDF file to show in <object> html tag in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do i generate a temporal PDF in my ASP.NET application so I get an temp URL for a generated PDF from an array of bytes ?

I use this but i think it could get simple:

```
//bytes[] arrayPDF exists before
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, arrayPDF);

HtmlGenericControl obj = new HtmlGenericControl("embed");
obj.Attributes.Add("src", fileName);
obj.Attributes.Add("style","border-radius: 10px;position: relative;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:620px;");
obj.Attributes.Add("height","600");
obj.Attributes.Add("type", "application/pdf");
form1.Controls.Add(obj);
```

My main problem is **how to generate a temp file that i am sure that it would not stay in the server more than the request/show time**

Comment: Generate it on the fly when requested from a dedicated URL. Don't generate it at the same time you generate the embedding page.

Comment: I have the bytes[] of the PDF and i want to show it in an object tag, appart from other divs, what you will recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [ASP.NET ASHX Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx):

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        // relevant context.Response lines
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101389/648075):

```
context.Response.Clear(); 
context.Response.ClearContent(); 
context.Response.ClearHeaders(); 
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Stream fileStream = publishBookManager.GetFile(documentId);
byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  int read;
  while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
  {
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
  }
}

context.Response.BinaryWrite(data); 
context.Response.Flush();
```