# How to convert binary data that stored at database back into a file as extention at other column using javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I need a help, I have a data in a SQL Server database like this:

```
 ----------------------------
| id | filename | filebinary |
 ----------------------------
|  1 | abc.png  | 0x89504E470| =>just part of correct binary
|  1 | def.xlsx | 0x504B03041| =>just part of correct binary
|  1 | ghi.pdf  | 0x255044462| =>just part of correct binary
|  1 | jkl.jpg  | 0x89504E470| =>just part of correct binary
 ----------------------------
```

How do I convert back the binary (column: `filebinary`) that stores a file in the database table as filename field at same row of table?

I try to find anything at google but cannot find the solution for this.

Can someone help me??

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to download the filebinary in web browser or return it as JSON back to client?

Comment: no, i already can get a file name and binary as javascript variable using json, now just confusing how to convert back the binary that i got as file that filename i already got too

Comment: so you have, for example, a png picture as array of bytes and need to show it in <img />?

Comment: no, i no need to show it, i need it as file that can be download like a attachment by user

Comment: What do you want to do with those files in the browser using JavaScript?

Comment: i want that file can be download like a attachment by user

Comment: why don't you create ASHX handler for it? You could have <a href=your handler url /> and download the file accordingly

Comment: how to do that.. i never do that?

Comment: it looks like you can chop it up into two-char chunks, the feed the chunks to something like parseInt(strChunk, 16) to get each byte value, which you can then feed to a blob or typed array, which you can then feed to a downloader script.

Comment: check this e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101361/return-pdf-to-webpage-from-ashx

Comment: i confusing in read the solution inside the link